# Ruby - Sinatra: Accessing "something" in a <p> element

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I have an array of courses in my server.rb, a course contains a name, a tutor, and an array of messages.
And then there's a .erb which lists all those messages. At the moment I grab the courses[0] and list the messages in it - but I want to give every available course its own messages displayed. In the .erb below is the list of all "subscribed" courses [atm just [0] - same problem).

Soo, is there a way, that I can get the string out of the p in the .erb for the search in the server.rb?

server.rb

```
post "/home" do
  search_item = params[:course]
  k = 0
    $courses.each do |course|
        if (course.course == search_item)
          $course_focused = $courses[k]     
            break
        else    
          k += 1
        end 
    end
end
```

---

.erb (snippet)

```
<% td = 0%>
    <% $verified_courses.each do |elem| %>
        <% if td < 3%>
            <td>
            <!-- <form action="/home" method="post"> -->
            <a href="/course">
            <div id="course_div">
            <p name="course">
            <%= elem.course %>
            </p>
            <br>
            <p id="tutor">
            <%= elem.tutor %>
            </p>
            </div>
            </a>
            <!-- </form> -->
            </td>
            <%  td += 1 %>
            <% elsif td == 3 %>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
```

I'm looking for a solution for hours, but cant't find anything. Hope, you can understand this. Haven't written or spoken english for years ...

---

EDIT:

course.rb

```
class Course
attr_accessor :course, :tutor, :key, :semester, :study_path

def initialize
    @messages = []
end

def addmessage (message)
    @messages.push message
end

def delmessage (todelete)
    i = 0
    while i < @messages.length
        if (todelete.date == message.date && todelete.header == message.header)
            @messages - [i]
            break
        else
            i += 1
        end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Can you please share the contents of `$courses` and/or `$verified_courses`? Also, you should not be using global variables ($this_is_a_global_variable) - use @instance_variables_like_this when you want to have a variable from server.rb accessible in your erb file.

Comment: In your route, rather than using `each` and testing each entry in turn, you are probably better using [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) — something like `course_focused = courses.find {|course| course.course == search_item }`.

Comment: Added the course.rb ... if that's what you meant.
And thanks for the hint with the global variables :)  Do I use them in the .erb the same way ('<% @courses ... %>')? Will edit that soon.

Comment: Could it work, if I set like <% params[:search_item] = elem.course %> <%= elem.course %> to get the search_item into the server.rb with a post method?

EDIT: No, doesn't ...

Comment: Now I may be more specific on what I need/want:
From server.rb you can get `<input type="text" name="post[name] .../>` from the erb file with `@name = params[:post][:name]`.
I need kinda exactly this, just for something that's not an input. In my case maybe a p-element in the erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.
May not be the beste solution but it works just fine.

All I did was replacing, the course-div with a submit button:

```
<form id="show" action="/course" method="get">
    <button type="submit" id="course_div" name="search_item" value="<%= elem.course %>">
    <%= elem.course %> 
    <br>
    <p id="tutor"><%= elem.tutor %></p>
    </button>
</form>
```

and then in the server.rb just grab the params[:search_item].

Comment: Could you accept your own answer, please (in stackoverflow terms)? Then other people like me can see that this question is ... answered already.